# How to include details in .exe properties menu

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, resource-files

I need to include information in the "Details" tab of the properties menu of a .exe program I am working on. From my understanding, I need to use a .rc resource file, and then modify the .csproj with a custom property so the compiler sees it.

Normally I would simply modify the AssemblyInfo file, but this is a Windows Mobile project, and .NET compact does not use/see this file.

Here is my .rc resource file. I know I am missing some #includes, but all the examples I've seen are in C++. (I've omitted the actual project details for security reasons):

```
VS_VERSION_INFO     VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION         0, 1, 0, 0
PRODUCTVERSION      0, 1, 0, 0
FILEFLAGSMASK       0x3fL
FILEFLAGS           0
FILEOS              VOS_NT_WINDOWS32
FILETYPE            VFT_APP
FILESUBTYPE         VFT2_UNKNOWN
BEGIN
   BLOCK   "VarFileInfo"
   BEGIN
        VALUE   "Translation",  0x409,  1200
    END
    BLOCK   "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK   "040904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE   "CompanyName",      "Company\0"
            VALUE   "FileDescription",  "Description\0"
            VALUE   "FileVersion",      "1.0.0\0"
            VALUE   "InternalName",     "Name\0"
            VALUE   "LegalCopyright",   "2014\0"
            VALUE   "OriginalFilename", "App.exe\0"
            VALUE   "ProductName",      "Product\0"
            VALUE   "ProductVersion",   "1.0.0\0"
        END
    END
END
```

As for modifying the .csproj, all I've come up with is this:

```
<!-- Add this at the end of project file (for C# project .csproj) -->
<PropertyGroup>
<CoreBuildDependsOn>
BuildOnlySettings;
PrepareForBuild;
PreBuildEvent;
UnmanagedUnregistration;
ResolveReferences;
PrepareResources;
ResolveKeySource;
Compile;
GenerateSerializationAssemblies;
CreateSatelliteAssemblies;
GenerateManifests;
GetTargetPath;
PrepareForRun;
UnmanagedRegistration;
IncrementalClean;
PostBuildEvent
</CoreBuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is my first post to the StackExchange, so please forgive any deficiencies in my etiquette.

Comment: **Project -> Properties -> Application** click Assembly Information

Comment: That doesn't work, as this is being deployed on Windows CE. The compiler doesn't look for it.